# how to use google firebase in my c# android xamarin project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am beginner android xamarin c# programmer i need any tutorial about how to use firebase in my c# android xamarin project that i knew it is easy and better than  classic databases as sql server and mysql that need webservice any help please

Comment: Refer this video tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SFrXsce431U

Comment: this is difficult explanation he did not set focus in the important point and very long period